# Problemas ao percorrer json aninhado

Tags: php, json, laravel

Tenho um ***response*** em json estou com um problemas para percorre-lo, o primeiro é que só consigo chegar até uma parte do json e não no valor que eu quero, o segundo que é que conseguente do primeiro é não estar percorrendo o número de ***response*** que ele me devolve. Por exemplo ele e retorna uma lista com 3 response porém só percorre e captura o valor de uma.

***Minha Resposta JSON***

```
[
  {
    "geocoded_waypoints": [
      {
        "geocoder_status": "OK",
        "place_id": "ChIJh5W-RbJzPIYRixw_andVya4",
        "types": [
          "establishment",
          "point_of_interest"
        ]
      },
      {
        "geocoder_status": "OK",
        "place_id": "ChIJeRXE_uZSeYYR7KP0sO1KcE8",
        "types": [
          "establishment",
          "food",
          "meal_takeaway",
          "point_of_interest",
          "restaurant"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "routes": [
      {
        "bounds": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": 30.1853475,
            "lng": -93.3394257
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": 23.7202912,
            "lng": -99.1646927
          }
        },
        "copyrights": "Map data ©2018 Google, INEGI",
        "legs": [
          {
            "distance": {
              "text": "695 mi",
              "value": 1118019
            },
            "duration": {
              "text": "11 hours 20 mins",
              "value": 40783
            },
            "end_address": "Calz Gral Luis Caballero 732, Zozaya, 87070 Cd Victoria, Tamps., Mexico",
            "end_location": {
              "lat": 23.7202912,
              "lng": -99.1646927
            },
            "start_address": "301 Main St, Hackberry, LA 70645, USA",
            "start_location": {
              "lat": 30.0351393,
              "lng": -93.3394257
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Obs:  Estou recebendo uma lista dessa mesma resposta, onde quero os valores especificos dessa lista.**

***Meu código***

```
<?php
    $v = [];
    $aux = [];
     foreach ($json as $dest) {
            foreach ($dest->routes as $key => $value) {
                foreach ($value->legs[0] as $k => $val) {
                    $aux = array( "distancia" => $val->distance->text, "lat" => $val->end_location->lat, "lng" => $val->end_location->lng );
                }
            }
        }
?>
```

***Obs:*** o valor que eu quero é o que está na varivel `$aux`, porém eu até consigo chegar mas ele só me retorna um dos valores da ***lista da resposta em json***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cada vez que você está montando uma `array` para adicionar na variável `$aux`, você está atribuindo o valor daquele momento e não adicionando ao vetor.

Você está fazendo assim:

```
$aux = array(...);
```

E deveria fazer assim:

```
$aux[] = array(...);
```

Ou

```
array_push($aux, array(...));
```

Comment: Então fiz como você falou, porém continuo tendo o mesmo resultado apena um único registro de uma lista de três, porém se eu subo um nível do loop ele me retorna os três registro mas não consigo pegar o valor que que quero.

Comment: Pode ser que no último `foreach` você está pegando apenas o primeiro item da `array`, tente assim: `foreach ($value->legs as $k => $val) {` . E no JSON que você mostrou só tem um resultado para a informação que você quer.

Comment: é verdade na resposta json só estava vindo um resultado.